Dirt Covering Brick with Water Barrier Ok?
I'm looking to makeover the front of my grey house (see attached picture). That means replacing the evergreen bushes with something new. I like the look of adding some hardscaping in front (maybe 1 ft high - at most) kind of like the two pictures at the bottom of the attached picture...different style but same idea.
So here comes my question. If I do that, that means I'm going to have to add some more soil, which would end up going against the brick of my house. Right now, the top of my foundation (you can see it circled in red), just barely peaks out above the soil and I've never had water issues. Before I add about 9 to 12 inches of soil, I'd put some sort of water barrier against the brick. Would that be acceptable for this situation? And if so, does anyone recommend anything in particular? Or should I completely abandon this idea? I'm not sure if this is a common situation/fix or what. Thanks in advance!



What is your wall construction?  Is that circled area your basement slab, or a basement wall?

I just added a picture/sketch to the original post. The circled section is the top of the foundation, which is behind the framing of the basement wall.

Are you sure you have a drain on the inside of the wall perimeter?  What kind of hardscape are you thinking of here?

I'm positive. Something similar to the two house on the bottom of my original picture. I'd consider other options too though - that don't require me to add soil. Just looking for something to sort of define the front. I'd even consider a raised bed...maybe 12" inches high but 12" away from the front of the house too to avoid adding the soil with a water barrier.

If you have a way to daylight it, you might consider installing a french drain outside the wall, along the top of the concrete wall.

Do not add dirt around your foundation.  A homes perimeter should have had the ground graded properly so there would not be an issue with water retention instigating issues within the home.
Sure you could add waterproofing to the outside. However a single crack in the barrier can be the seed to a series of issues that you end up fighting for years.  Why risk it when you do not need to.
You say you have no problems. You are blessed. Don't create something in the interest of being pretty that could cause misery down the road.
You can achieve a very similar look without having a raised planting bed. We do not give advice here on decoration or landscaping for esthetics. However you can have a beautifully landscaped home and keep the proper grading that you currently have.

Thanks for the response. I understand what you're saying. Fortunately it's nothing I have to do...just brainstorming ideas and always open to feedback.
